# A Convex Hull function

Tags: convex-hull

I am new to StackOverflow, and this is my first question here.

I was solving few problems on Convex Hull and on seeing the answer submissions of vjudges on Codechef, I found that they repeatedly used the following function to find out the convex hull of a set of points.

```
int n = (int)p.size();
if (n <= 1)
    return p;
sort(p.begin(), p.end());
int cnt = 0;
vector<Pint> q(n * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < n; q[cnt++] = p[i++])
    for (; cnt >= 2 && !cw(q[cnt - 2], q[cnt - 1], p[i]); --cnt)
        ;
for (int i = n - 2, t = cnt; i >= 0; q[cnt++] = p[i--])
    for (; cnt > t && !cw(q[cnt - 2], q[cnt - 1], p[i]); --cnt)
        ;
q.resize(cnt - 1 - (q[0] == q[1]));
return q;
```

Can somebody explain what is the logic behind this function, is it something different than Jarvis or Graham's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code uses a little different algorithm from Grahm's or Jarvis algorithm.
It first finds upper half hull and then lower half hull by applying the same algorithm in reverse order. Finally, it combines both.

Input: A set P of points in the plane.
Output: A list containing the vertices of CH(P) in clockwise order.

```
 1. Sort the points by x-coordinate, resulting in a sequence p1,p2.....pn
 2. Put the points p1 and p2 in a list Lupper, with p1 as the first point
 3. for i from 3 to n
 4.     do Append pi to Lupper
 5.          while length(Lupper)>2 and last three points in Lupper make left turn
 6.               do delete middle of last three points from Lupper
```

Now put the points pn,pn-1 in a list Llower with pn as first point

```
 7. for i from n-2 to 1
 8.     do Append pi to Llower
 9.          while length(Llower)>2 and last three points in Llower make left turn
 10.               do delete middle of last three points from Llower
 11. Remove the first and last point from Llower to avoid duplication of the points where upper and lower hull meet.
 12. Append Llower to Lupper and call the resulting list L
 13. return L
```

For example:- points = (0,0),(1,1),(2,5),(8,9),(10,0),(1,-1),(2,-5),(8,-9)

[Lupper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N76mM.png)

[Llower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS2mh.png)

[Final Hull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDyZ6.png)

Algorithm Source: Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications by Mark de Berg